# Ext JS - Creating a new application

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs5

I have installed SenchaCmd-6.0.2.14-windows-64bit.exe and it installed into the folder C:\users\myname\bin....

I am trying to create a new app. I have tried the cmd given in the sencha site. But it says "Not a framework directory".

Kindly help me to start it... I am new to Extjs

Comment: You mean this command: `sencha -sdk /path/to/extjs/framework generate app AppName path/to/app`? If yes, then the error message is quite obvious. The path to the sdk does not contain the ext js framework. You should double check the path.
If you copied the extracted extjs source folders to c:\Dev\Frameworks\ExtJs, the the command must be something like `sencha -sdk c:\Dev\Frameworks\ExtJs generate app MySuperApp c:\Dev\Projects\MySuperApp`

Answer (score 1):

After downloading Sencha CMD you'll need to download the EXT JS SDK or you can download the GPL version. You can get them from official Sencha website (as you would have downloaded Sencha CMD).

Then you can generate the app by specifying the location where you have kept the EXT JS SDK or else, navigate to location where you have kept the EXT JS SDK using command prompt, then give the generate command. For example.

```
D:\ext-6.0.2-trial\ext-6.0.2>sencha generate app YouAppName <location>
```

Specify the location where you want to create the files of the application, usually the c:\inetpub\wwwroot directory if you are using IIS server on Windows.